# HCatalog configured with Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig, hcatalog

I'm wondering if anyone knows of a good tutorial for installing HCatalog on top of Hive so I can load data in via Hive, query via Impala and also run some scripts using Pig?

I'm wondering if downloading the VM from Cloudera would be the best option but I haven't seen many tutorials (that are clear with config steps) to get HCatalog running with Hive!

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is probably to download the cloudera distribution, especially if you want to get impala going as well.

Comment: Thanks Simon! Do you know of any instructions on putting HCatalog over Hive?

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Hive 0.12, HCatalog comes with hive. You do not need separate installation or start hcat server. Use the appropriate mechanisms to access hcat managed tables from different mapreduce tools (Pig, java map-reduce programs)